# phpmailer working on site but not on localhost

Tags: php, email, localhost, phpmailer

I'm trying to send mail from my localhost using phpmailer, but it's not working. I literally copied and pasted a working version of the code (which works from my website), but when I try to send mail it gives me the following errors:

```
SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Operation timed out (60) 
SMTP connect() failed.
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

Things I've tried:

Commenting out lines with SMTP (which fails without giving error message)

Changing port number to 25 or 465

Making sure that everything works in its current form on my actual website

```
require_once("vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();


$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host       = "example.com";
$mail->Port       = 587;
$mail->Username   = "username@example.com";
$mail->Password   = "password";



$mail->From = "username@example.com";
$mail->FromName = "name";

$mail->addAddress("user@gmail.com");


$mail->Subject = "Subject";
$mail->Body = "Body";

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else {
    echo "Message has been sent successfully";
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you actually have an SMTP server listening on port 587 which your local machine can access via the value of `$mail->Host`? And have you actually changed that value from `"example.com"`? You can test your SMTP server with `telnet`.

Comment: Since it looks like you're using PHPMailer via composer, why aren't you using composer's autoloader? It might help to read the readme, and the troubleshooting guide, and make sure you're using the latest version.

Comment: @ironchicken Yes to both. Telnet says I'm connected, and I only changed values when I posted the code here

Comment: @Synchro I tried with and without composer, didn't work either way

Comment: So do what the guide says in order to diagnose it. You should search before posting- there are many duplicates of this question.

Comment: @Synchro Which guide are you referring to? If it's the one on phpmailer's wiki I did look there before posting. I also tried to find similar posts here but didn't find anything that solved the problem.